# Creating dataframes in Python: issue with columns and index

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a DataFrame with multiple indices and one column. If I type the following:

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [1000000,1,1] ,index=['Cash'],columns=['a','b','c'] )
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 3), indices imply (3, 1)
```

If I change the array to columns, like:

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [[1000000],[1],[1]] ,index=['Cash'],columns=['a','b','c'] )
```

then the error I have is:

```
AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

Do you know why this is happening?

One solution is to do:

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [1000000,1,1] ,columns=['Cash'],index=['a','b','c'] ).T
```

but doesn't look very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're assigning `index` as `'Cash'` which is only 1 index.
and `[1000000,1,1]` is passing 3 rows of data.

And look at this:

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [1000000,1,1] ,columns=['Cash'],index=['a','b','c'] ).T
```

You're passing 3 rows of data, 1 x columns and 3 indexes, which matches the structure of a dataframe.

However think of the arrays in a DataFrame like `x`,`y` coordinates as in `columns`, `rows` structure, here should be what your DataFrame looks like:

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [[1000000, 1, 1]] ,columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],index=['cash'] )
```

`[[10000000, 1, 1]]` translates to like on `rows[0]`, `columns[0], columns[1], columns[2] = ...`, with columns label `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'` and 1 x index `'cash'`.

Alternatively,

```
InitialPosition=pd.DataFrame( [[1000000],[1],[1]] ,columns=['Cash'],index=['a','b','c'] ).T
```

which, `[[1000000], [1], [1]]` translates to `rows[0], columns[0] = [1000000]`, `rows[1], columns[0] = 1`, `rows[2], columns[0] = 1`, with 1 x column `'Cash'`, and 3 x indexes `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'` accordingly, then transpose it at the end.

Both will give you this result:

```
InitialPosition

            a  b  c
cash  1000000  1  1
```

And I strong advise you read this [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html) which explains things rather thoroughly yet not too hard to digest.

Comment: Thank you Anzel, for such a detailed answer. That makes a lot of sense.